# Parsing Excel XML into R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, parsing

Hi I know there are many packages to do this, but none have worked on this particular file of mine.

I need to parse this file from XML into a data-frame. It should ignore all of the formatting and just give me my data.

I've tried XML, XML2, OPENXLSX, TIDYXL, READR, and XLSX packages and none can do it. Either they say it's not an XLS/XLXS file or a jumble of data

```
library(XML)
fileurl <- "pep_slim.xml"
doc <- xmlParse(fileurl,useInternalNodes = TRUE) 
doc
xL <- xmlToList(doc)
data <- ldply(xL, data.frame)
head(data)
```

Full file is below and ends in *.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Proctor, Stephon N</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Stephon Proctor</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2019-09-25T13:30:11Z</Created>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>10590</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>25440</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <RefModeR1C1/>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#4F81BD" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s63">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#4FBD81" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s64">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#A081BD" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s65">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#D85647" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s66">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FF9900" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s67">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Top" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#020202"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="MetricData">
  <Names>
   <NamedRange ss:Name="_FilterDatabase" ss:RefersTo="=MetricData!R1C1:R1C15"
    ss:Hidden="1"/>
  </Names>
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="15" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80.25" ss:Span="2"/>
   <Column ss:Index="4" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="159.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="90" ss:Span="3"/>
   <Column ss:Index="9" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="140.25" ss:Span="1"/>
   <Column ss:Index="11" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="159.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80.25" ss:Span="2"/>
   <Column ss:Index="15" ss:Width="60.75"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Type</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">EmpCID</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">SerCID</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">ProviderName</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">ProviderType</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">ServiceArea</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Department</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Specialty</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">UserType</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">ReportingPeriodStartDate</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">ReportingPeriodEndDate</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Metric</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">Numerator</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">Denominator</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">Value</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="60">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">Provider</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="Number">123413</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="Number">234123</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">Person's Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">NURSE PRACTITIONER</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">CHOP SERVICE AREA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">VIRTUA ORTHOPEDICS</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">Orthopedics</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">Non-Physician</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">7/28/2019</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">8/31/2019</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">Messages Received per Day - Encounter Report</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="Number">21</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Unsynced/>
   <Selected/>
   <FreezePanes/>
   <FrozenNoSplit/>
   <SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
   <TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
   <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
     <Number>2</Number>
     <ActiveCol>3</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
  <AutoFilter x:Range="R1C1:R1C15"
   xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  </AutoFilter>
 </Worksheet>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook/>
 <ss:UserWebMetaData>
   <ss:UserFirstName>Stephon</ss:UserFirstName>
   <ss:UserLastName>Proctor</ss:UserLastName>
   <ss:UserFirstEmail>proctors@email.chop.edu</ss:UserFirstEmail>
   <ss:UserID>29c3862c-57c8-487c-8f79-5d50e87af7a7</ss:UserID>
   <ss:Instant>9/24/2019 11:51:52 AM</ss:Instant>
  </ss:UserWebMetaData>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: and are you sure it is a valid excel-file? Have you tried opening an re-saving using excel? (when many files, use a vba-macro to do this). Alto, try using read_excel() from the the readxl-package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `xmlToDataFrame` to extract your specific data items, then run a migration of headers being first 15 extracted items and finally `reshape` from long to wide. Since XML maintains a default namespace, a temporary prefix, *doc*, is assigned for parsing. Below assumes consistency of 15 columns of non-missing *Cell/Data* nodes.

```
library(XML)
fileurl <- "pep_slim.xml"

doc <- xmlParse(fileurl)     
nmsp <- c(doc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")    
df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//doc:Cell", nmsp))

df$Headers <- df$Data[1:15]                  # ASSIGN HEADERS TO EVERY 15 ROWS
df <- with(df, df[Data != Headers,])         # SUBSET OUT ORIGINAL HEADERS

# ADD 1-15 ID SEQUENCE (FOR RESHAPING)
df$id <- with(df, ave(as.integer(NamedCell), Headers, FUN=seq_along))

# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG WITH CLEANUP OF NAMES
rdf <- reshape(df, v.names = "Data", timevar="Headers", idvar="id",
               drop = "NamedCell", direction="wide", sep="_")

colnames(rdf) <- gsub("Data_", "", colnames(rdf))
rownames(rdf) <- NULL
```

Output

```
rdf
#   id     Type EmpCID SerCID  ProviderName       ProviderType       ServiceArea         Department   Specialty      UserType
# 1  1 Provider 123413 234123 Person's Name NURSE PRACTITIONER CHOP SERVICE AREA VIRTUA ORTHOPEDICS Orthopedics Non-Physician
#   ReportingPeriodStartDate ReportingPeriodEndDate                                       Metric Numerator Denominator Value
# 1                7/28/2019              8/31/2019 Messages Received per Day - Encounter # Report         0          21     0
```

Comment: YASSSS!! This was perfect.