# Parsing Excel XML into R with row index value

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, parsing, indexing

I am looking to parse an Excel formatted XML (example file below) into R. The answer here ([Parsing Excel XML into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102084/parsing-excel-xml-into-r)) got me pretty close, but there is one last step I can't figure out. My R code (below) gives me all the XML data in a single column *without* the associated row index values. In these data, there are 23 "headers" which will eventually be shaped into rows. The catch is that not every entry has all 23 pieces of data, so I need the row index to shape my data properly after it has been parsed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="Header1">
<Borders>
 <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
 <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
 <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
 <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" />
</Borders>
<Font ss:Bold="1"/>
<Interior ss:Color="#D8F6D8" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
</Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="OfficeAppointments">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="23">
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Doctor</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Period</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Appt Date</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Patient</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Type</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="6" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Avail</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="7" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Init</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="8" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Acct</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="9" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Loc</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="10" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Status</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="11" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Note</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="12" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Memo 1</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="13" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Memo 2</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="14" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Referring Dr#</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="15" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Referring Dr Name</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="16" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Sex</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="17" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Chart</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="18" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Date Of Birth</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="19" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Age</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="20" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">HIPAA Priv Alert</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="21" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Supervising Dr</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="22" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">PCP #</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="23" ss:StyleID="Header1">
         <Data ss:Type="String">PCP Name</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">10:00a</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">04/23/20</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">OV</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="6" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">N</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="7" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">SB</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="9" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">O</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="10" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">D</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="11" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">Note gets typed here</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">10:30a</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">04/23</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String"> NAME </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">OV</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="6" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">N</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="7" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">sb</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="8" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">73104</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="9" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">O</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="10" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">B</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="11" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">follow up</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="14" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">32</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="15" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">NAME, CREDENTIALS</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="16" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">SEX</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="18" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">DOB entered here</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="19" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">5</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="20" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="22" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">32</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:Index="23" ss:StyleID="Default">
         <Data ss:Type="String">NAME, CREDENTIALS</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
 </Table>
 <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <Selected/>
  <FreezePanes/>
  <FrozenNoSplit/>
  <SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
  <TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
  <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
  <Panes>
   <Pane>
    <Number>3</Number>
   </Pane>
   <Pane>
    <Number>2</Number>
   </Pane>
  </Panes>
  <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
  <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
 </WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

My R code so far:

```
library(XML)
nmsp <- c(doc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")
fileurl <- "example.xml"
doc <- xmlParse(fileurl) 
df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//doc:Cell", nmsp), collectNames = T, homogeneous = F)
```

What my code gives me:

```
   Data                
   <chr>               
 1 Doctor              
 2 Period              
 3 Appt Date           
 4 Patient             
 5 Type                
 6 Avail               
 7 Init                
 8 Acct                
 9 Loc                 
10 Status              
11 Note                
12 Memo 1              
13 Memo 2              
14 Referring Dr#       
15 Referring Dr Name   
16 Sex                 
17 Chart               
18 Date Of Birth       
19 Age                 
20 HIPAA Priv Alert    
21 Supervising Dr      
22 PCP #               
23 PCP Name            
24 1                   
25 10:00a              
26 04/23/20            
27 OV                  
28 N                   
29 SB                  
30 O                   
31 D                   
32 Note gets typed here
33 1                   
34 10:30a              
35 04/23               
36 NAME                
37 OV                  
38 N                   
39 sb                  
40 73104               
41 O                   
42 B                   
43 follow up           
44 32                  
45 NAME, CREDENTIALS   
46 SEX                 
47 DOB entered here    
48 5                   
49 No                  
50 32                  
51 NAME, CREDENTIALS
```

What I need:

```
   Data                 Index
   <chr>                <dbl>
 1 Doctor                   1
 2 Period                   2
 3 Appt Date                3
 4 Patient                  4
 5 Type                     5
 6 Avail                    6
 7 Init                     7
 8 Acct                     8
 9 Loc                      9
10 Status                  10
11 Note                    11
12 Memo 1                  12
13 Memo 2                  13
14 Referring Dr#           14
15 Referring Dr Name       15
16 Sex                     16
17 Chart                   17
18 Date Of Birth           18
19 Age                     19
20 HIPAA Priv Alert        20
21 Supervising Dr          21
22 PCP #                   22
23 PCP Name                23
24 1                        1
25 10:00a                   2
26 04/23/20                 3
27 OV                       5
28 N                        6
29 SB                       7
30 O                        9
31 D                       10
32 Note gets typed here    11
33 1                        1
34 10:30a                   2
35 04/23                    3
36 NAME                     4
37 OV                       5
38 N                        6
39 sb                       7
40 73104                    8
41 O                        9
42 B                       10
43 follow up               11
44 32                      14
45 NAME, CREDENTIALS       15
46 SEX                     16
47 DOB entered here        18
48 5                       19
49 No                      20
50 32                      22
51 NAME, CREDENTIALS       23
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `xmlToDataFrame` on *Cell* element values, consider the internal (undocumented) method in `XML` to parse *Cell* attributes to data frame: `xmlAttrsToDataframe` accessible via the triple colon operator. From there, call `cbind` on two data series.

```
elem_df <- XML::xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, path="//doc:Cell", namespace=nmsp))

attrib_df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path="//doc:Cell", namespace=nmsp))$Index
    
final_df <- cbind.data.frame(Data=elem_df, Index=attrib_df)
```

**Output**

```
final_df
#                    Data Index
# 1                Doctor     1
# 2                Period     2
# 3             Appt Date     3
# 4               Patient     4
# 5                  Type     5
# 6                 Avail     6
# 7                  Init     7
# 8                  Acct     8
# 9                   Loc     9
# 10               Status    10
# 11                 Note    11
# 12               Memo 1    12
# 13               Memo 2    13
# 14        Referring Dr#    14
# 15    Referring Dr Name    15
# 16                  Sex    16
# 17                Chart    17
# 18        Date Of Birth    18
# 19                  Age    19
# 20     HIPAA Priv Alert    20
# 21       Supervising Dr    21
# 22                PCP #    22
# 23             PCP Name    23
# 24                    1     1
# 25               10:00a     2
# 26             04/23/20     3
# 27                   OV     5
# 28                    N     6
# 29                   SB     7
# 30                    O     9
# 31                    D    10
# 32 Note gets typed here    11
# 33                    1     1
# 34               10:30a     2
# 35                04/23     3
# 36                NAME      4
# 37                   OV     5
# 38                    N     6
# 39                   sb     7
# 40                73104     8
# 41                    O     9
# 42                    B    10
# 43            follow up    11
# 44                   32    14
# 45    NAME, CREDENTIALS    15
# 46                  SEX    16
# 47     DOB entered here    18
# 48                    5    19
# 49                   No    20
# 50                   32    22
# 51    NAME, CREDENTIALS    23
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if we use the `xml2` package:

```r
library(xml2)

myxml <- read_xml("example.xml")

Rows     <- myxml %>% xml_ns_strip() %>% xml_find_all("//Row")
cells    <- Rows %>% lapply(xml_children)
indices  <- lapply(cells, function(x) as.numeric(xml_attr(x, "Index")))
n_row    <- lapply(seq_along(indices), function(i) rep(i, length(indices[[i]])))
contents <- lapply(cells, xml_text)

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(indices), function(i){
  data.frame(row = n_row[[i]], col = indices[[i]], value = contents[[i]])
}))
```

So now our data frame contains the row, column and contents for easy indexing:

```
df
#>    row col                value
#> 1    1   1               Doctor
#> 2    1   2               Period
#> 3    1   3            Appt Date
#> 4    1   4              Patient
#> 5    1   5                 Type
#> 6    1   6                Avail
#> 7    1   7                 Init
#> 8    1   8                 Acct
#> 9    1   9                  Loc
#> 10   1  10               Status
#> 11   1  11                 Note
#> 12   1  12               Memo 1
#> 13   1  13               Memo 2
#> 14   1  14        Referring Dr#
#> 15   1  15    Referring Dr Name
#> 16   1  16                  Sex
#> 17   1  17                Chart
#> 18   1  18        Date Of Birth
#> 19   1  19                  Age
#> 20   1  20     HIPAA Priv Alert
#> 21   1  21       Supervising Dr
#> 22   1  22                PCP #
#> 23   1  23             PCP Name
#> 24   2   1                    1
#> 25   2   2               10:00a
#> 26   2   3             04/23/20
#> 27   2   5                   OV
#> 28   2   6                    N
#> 29   2   7                   SB
#> 30   2   9                    O
#> 31   2  10                    D
#> 32   2  11 Note gets typed here
#> 33   3   1                    1
#> 34   3   2               10:30a
#> 35   3   3                04/23
#> 36   3   4                NAME 
#> 37   3   5                   OV
#> 38   3   6                    N
#> 39   3   7                   sb
#> 40   3   8                73104
#> 41   3   9                    O
#> 42   3  10                    B
#> 43   3  11            follow up
#> 44   3  14                   32
#> 45   3  15    NAME, CREDENTIALS
#> 46   3  16                  SEX
#> 47   3  18     DOB entered here
#> 48   3  19                    5
#> 49   3  20                   No
#> 50   3  22                   32
#> 51   3  23    NAME, CREDENTIALS
```